# Mac Messages suggestions ordering

Tags: messages, contacts

I use Messages (most recent version) on Mac (High Sierra - 10.13.1). When starting a new conversation, Messages suggests two contacts when I type a particular first name. (They share a first name). Unfortunately, it suggests the wrong one and I was hoping to fix that.

More info: The last name I want starts with an 'H' and alphabetically comes before the 'V'. The reason I think they're swapped is that the 'H' is an Android and thus does not support iMessage, whereas 'V' is an iPhone. Neither number is a contact, at least not in the Contacts app. I'd be fine doing something like putting a '1' in front of the wrong one so it doesn't come up when I search.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried adding nicknames to them in Contacts?  After you do this, just type their nickname in Messages to get the correct one.

Comment: That's a better alternative to just adding the '1', but neither is in contacts. I could add them, but I'm unsure of where their records are currently. (There are many names and numbers in messages that don't have contacts)

Comment: That's understandable. The quickest solution is to add their names to contacts, you only need their names. Nicknames will give you the fastest, easiest solution.